# October CMS overriding list query

Tags: laravel, octobercms

In backend I have a list of records. And this list displays all records of this type. It is possible to override this query?

In controller I have Eloquent query and i grab some data from database, 
and i set this data in $query_data variable. Howe push this data in list view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unfortunately, I didn't get exactly your point of telling override query, if you mean that set some condition in fetching data from database in Eloquent you have to use **where** for example in the example below we have users which their gender is male:

```
$users=User::where('gender','male')->get();
```

for set more condition you can do like this:

```
$users=User::where([['gender','male'],['status',1]])->get();
```

and for showing the variable in your view you can use compact method:

```
return view('YOUR BLADE FILE NAME',compact('users'));
```

hope be helpful bro

Comment: @NGrdanjski thanks god ! but I told you exactly that bro with more details! :)